# Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type tag 67 found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

- First, I used **Android Studio 2.3 Beta 2** to create a new project with **Navigation Drawer Activity** template.

In the **content_main.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context="com.waylanpunch.event.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

There was an error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'parent'
```

FULL LOG:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
D:\WORKGROUP\WORKSPACES\Android_Studio_WORKSPACE\Event\app\src\main\res\layout\content_main.xml
Error:(16, 49) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(17, 45) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(18, 47) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(19, 43) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' with value 'parent').
D:\WORKGROUP\WORKSPACES\Android_Studio_WORKSPACE\Event\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\content_main.xml
Error:(16, 49) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(17, 45) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(18, 47) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' with value 'parent').
Error:(19, 43) String types not allowed (at 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' with value 'parent').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.786 secs
Information:9 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

**What's the problem with the symbol 'parent'?**

- Sencond, I change ConstraintLayout to Framelayout

In the **content_main.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context="com.waylanpunch.event.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</FrameLayout>
```

During the process of **BUILD**, despite the error below(2nd line), the **BUILD** was successful.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type tag 67 found.
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 2.523 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

And I didn't know where the **IllegalArgumentException** issue came from.

Anyone can help me ? Thanks!

Comment: can you post full error

Comment: can you show the line number of your xml's

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Are you sure that you copied your code properly?

Comment: have you added constraintLayout library in gradle

Comment: below is the library you have to add with    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'

Comment: To  **Redman**, I added the full log and I just use AS to create a new project without changing anything, so the code is what it looks like oringal.                           To  **Ahamed**, I have constraintLayout library in gradle otherwise the AS cannot resolve the constraintLayout symbol.                                                                     To **Divers**, did you use **Android Studio 2.3 Beta 2** ?

Comment: Since Divers said the code works fine for him, I assume the problem is caused by the **Beta 2** version

Comment: Thank you all, I will leave it to **Android Studio 2.3 Stable** version, the newest version might not be perfect

Comment: What's wrong with parent? You can't have a string, like the error says. It has to be a `@id/` reference

Comment: Hi @cricket_007, it is a default value when you use **Android Studio 2.3 Beta 2** to create a **Navigation Drawer Activity** project. And '''@id/''' is good, it is Beta version cause the parent symbol issue. But the second problem

Comment: Well, still I don't think a constraint to the top/left/right/buttom all of the parent makes sense. You're essentially using match parent width and height at that point, which you already have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be using an old version of ConstraintLayout. Be sure to use a recent version -- beta 4 or newer (We introduced the parent tag support in constraintlayout alpha 5...).

Comment: **1.0.0-alpha4** is the newest version of **ConstraintLayout**, check https://bintray.com/ligboy/maven/constraint-layout

Comment: Well :-) I can assure you that alpha 4 is not the newest version of ConstraintLayout. Please check http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayoutbeta4isnowavailable . You should get the official version from the SDK Manager, not from bintray -- I don't know who did that.

Comment: Oh, yes, someone made that, but AS did reference to his library at the first place, that's strange. I will update it and try it again. Thanks @Nicolas Roard

Comment: @WaylanPunch Today I got the same error, but I do not use ConstraintLayout, what helped you? I checked all layouts and there do not have any error "Can not resolve symbol", after BUILD in console I got error "Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type tag 67 found.", But do not know where.

Comment: @waki could you solve it? I got the same error today

Comment: Invalidate Caches/Restart fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve a similar problem by restarting Android Studio.

Here is my condition. I did some changes on .java file not .xml file then suddenly when I built the project, I always got the following messages

```
Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type tag 67 found.
```